# custom fields anchor points php

Tags: php, custom-field

Hey i have a list on the side of one of my pages which when clicking on the word it scrolls to its anchor which is set up like:

```
<div class="guide-section"  id="Measuring_up">
```

then the href looks like this:

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#Measuring_up">Measuring up</a>
```

My question is I have made the guide section dynamic in WordPress using custom post type and linking it which is working how I want to it but the list items are not. is there a way in PHP to get an id from custom fields which I have setup like:

custom field: guide_id
value: Measuring_up

Thank You

EDIT: Updated code(infinite list)

```
<?php
                    if( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){
                        while( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){ $bedGuideRight_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php global $post;?> 
                <div class="guide-section"  id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                </div>
                <?php }
                    } else { ?>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="testimonial">
                                <h3>No Bed Guides Found</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 sidebar">
                <div class="panel panel-success guide ">
                  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Guides</strong></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><small>Click on any of the listings below to quickly find the information you need.</small></p>
                  </div>

                  <ul class="list-group">
                  <?php if( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){
                    while( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){ $bedGuideRight_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php }
                    } ?>
                  </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Comment: Just follow the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wanna do is use the `name` attribute.

```
<a href="#my-anchor">Link to the anchor</a>

<p name="my-anchor">This is the anchor</p>
```

Also, I would use something consistent, like the post/page slug to be able to link to each section.

```
<?php global $post; ?>

<div class="guide-section" name="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
```

And then for your list use the slug as well. Repeat the while-loop:

```
<?php if( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){
   while( $bedGuideRight_query->have_posts() ){
     $bedGuideRight_query->the_post(); ?>
     <a class="list-group-item" href="#<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: not sure i understand what your correcting as i believe i am already using this method for my anchor points

Comment: You set it in a `id` attribute, it should be set in the `name` attribute. Also please clarify your question.

Comment: right I have changed it to name if you look on my edit above. I need all them anchors to work but my php code only allows one, so is there away to set the name to a custom field on WP?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: If you do want it done with custom fields, how have you set up your custom fields?

Comment: I've edited the above code I understood what you meant but I think I've done it wrong. my custom field is setup the name is guide_id and the value is like the anchor in HTML

Comment: I've updated my answer. You simply need to repeat the loop; otherwise you'll get the same value for each <a>-tag. And add an `echo` in the href.

Comment: does post_name need to be the name of the post or will it automatically find it so leave it like post_name?

Comment: You can use whatever you want, but `post_name` will always be unique since it's the URL-friendly title of the post/page.

Comment: This method works but when clicking on the list it takes me to the post page instead of the scroll to the box

Comment: You need to add the '#' in front. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Right I have done that but its not scrolls the url changes to #postname but it does not scroll to the box

Comment: Changing from name to id seems to work

Comment: You should check the code to see if the `name` attribute in your guide-section div, matches the `href`attribute on your link.

Comment: yes it is working but it makes a infinite list on the side now

Comment: Sorry its because i have so many loops of the list :L hahaha stupid me, Thank you for your help with this